# How to set mapping for grunt-lesslint

Tags: css, gruntjs, less, lint, csslint

I've got lots of imports in my main.less file, and lesslint imports/lints them all properly, but the problem is - I can't see any mapping for linting errors, so I can't understand which of less files contains the error. Is there any idea how to set it properly?

I set it like that:

```
    lesslint: {
      src: ['less/main.less'],
      options: {
        imports: ['less/*.less'],
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At https://github.com/jgable/grunt-lesslint you will find:

> Generating reports
>
> This plugin provides the same output formatter options as the [CSS Lint
>   plugin](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Command-line-interface#--format) and can be configured similarly:

```
lesslint:
  options:
    formatters: [
      id: 'csslint-xml'
      dest: 'report/lesslint.xml'
    ]
```